# Migrating typed data sets from .net 2.0 to 3.5

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, strongly-typed-dataset

I'm migrating a quite big application from .net 2.0 to 3.5 and the first challenge I'm facing is related to typed data sets.

Seems that the generated code for .net 2.0 is not compatible with above versions but the built-in migration process didn't convert them so now I'm getting a lot of errors and I'm not sure what to do.

Anyone know any practical way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?

Comment: @Marc: Well, didn't specify errors since seems not very relevant from my point of view. The underlying model just changed and old code it's just deprecaded (e.g. methods and properties doesn't exist anymore). More than solve the specific errors I want a clean migration of the typed data sets. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on each dataset file in solution explorer and choose "Run custom tool" to regenerate the files.

Comment: I'll be checking on this. Thanks Albin!